# How to store kafka topic into db using connectors

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I want to store key from topic to column MY KEY and value from topic to column MY_VALUE

I tried:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: my connector
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: kafka
spec:
  class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    connection.url: url
    connection.user: user
    connection.password: pass
    topics: MY_TOPIC
    key.converter: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    value.converter: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    key.converter.schema.registry.url: http://schemaregistry.kafka:8085
    value.converter.schema.registry.url: http://schemaregistry.kafka:8085
    auto.create: false
    auto.evolve: false
    insert.mode: update
    fields.whitelist: MY_KEY,MY_VALUE
    table.name.format: MY_TABLE
```

but I got exception

```
 No fields found using key and value schemas for table
```

what property is missing in my configuration ?

**UPDATE:**

here simple db:

```
CREATE TABLE POM_BL_LOG (
  MY_KEY VARCHAR2(50),
  MY_VALUE CLOB,
  MY_TS TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

and content in kafka:

```
{"MY_ID":3601}

{
  "MY_ID": 3601,
  "MY_INT": 3,
  "MY_NUMBER": 1685461149147
}
```

but it could be anything not just avro for example key String and value some json where I dont want to extract anything just store this whole value to db

Comment: Please show your table definition and an example Avro record/schema

Comment: ok table is simple just value/key columnt and content in kafka could be anything not just avro for example string/json to store this into db

Comment: Well, it cannot "be anything". You've explicitly set AvroConverter, so it must be Avro. JDBC sink won't accept schemaless string records... I think the error is saying your table is missing a primary key (what are your kafka record keys)? Ref https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/

Comment: but when you have in kafka StringKeyConverter key and JsonValueConverter then it should also work. And key you can see in questions: {"MY_ID":3601} but in other topic it could be String like 11111:22222

Comment: Try it. It'll fail to write schemaless data because there is no column information

Answer (score 0):

You've white-listed `MY_KEY,MY_VALUE` fields, but those aren't part of your shown record data. Therefore, as the error says, it cannot find any fields to write for keys or values

The field names in the Kafka records must match table columns. You can set `transforms` to rename fields before they reach the table

If you delete the table and set these, it'll create the table correctly for you

```
auto.create: true
auto.evolve: true
```

Comment: but that is the problem I dont want to insert fields. I want to store whole value of key or value. Whole content of key insert to first column and whole content of value insert to second column

Comment: That's not possible with JDBC sink unless you use a bytes type Avro schema and store with some `"content"` field name+database column.

Comment: Mongo, Redis, or S3 sink would be better uses for that

Comment: hm I can use other Sink connector. where I can store value from kafka to oracle

Comment: I don't have experience with Oracle. JDBC Sink connector itself has the limitations I am saying, not a specific database